# Why asynchttpclient in tornado don't send request immediately?

Tags: python, tornado, nonblocking, asynchttpclient

At one point, I need a lot of time to submit a non-blocking request and for 2 seconds, with a tornado write an example, help me!

I have a Server Client program in python which uses Tornado.

Server.py :

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import random
import time

def handle_request(request):
    t = random.randint(1, 10) / 10.
    _str = "%s rep_time: %s delay %s" % (request.body, time.time(), t)
    time.sleep(t)
    request.write('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %s\r\n\r\n%s' % (len(_str), _str))
    request.finish()

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(handle_request)
http_server.listen(8888)
print "server start..."
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

client.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient, HTTPRequest
import tornado.ioloop
import time
from tornado.log import gen_log
from tornado import gen
from tornado.options import parse_command_line
import datetime

@gen.coroutine
def handle_requst(response):
    if response.body:
        gen_log.info("response body: %s" % response.body)

@gen.coroutine
def send_request(num):
    yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch("http://localhost:8888", handle_requst, method="POST", body="req_time: %s no.: %s" % (time.time(), num))

@gen.coroutine
def run():
    begin_time = int(time.time() + 1)
    while True:
        yield gen.Task(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout, datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))
        now_time = int(time.time())

        if now_time == begin_time: 
            gen_log.info('begin_time:%s' % time.time())
            num = 0
            while True:
                num = num + 1
                if num < 10:
                    #Begin submitting data
                    send_request(num)
                # Submit two seconds
                if time.time() > (begin_time + 2):
                    break
            break
    gen_log.info('end_time:%s' % time.time())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_command_line()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(run)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

result

```
[I 141230 19:05:32 2:24] begin_time:1419937532.08
[I 141230 19:05:34 2:36] end_time:1419937534.0
[I 141230 19:05:34 2:11] response body: req_time: 1419937532.1 no.: 1 rep_time: 1419937534.0 delay 0.1
```

Begin time: 32s 
End time: 34s 
request time: 32s  
server accept time: 34s

As you can see the server accept time is 34s, I want server accept time to be around 32s

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't have tornado installed to check, but if you change

```
yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch("http://localhost:8888", handle_requst, method="POST", body="req_time: %s no.: %s" % (time.time(), num))
```

to:

```
AsyncHTTPClient().fetch("http://localhost:8888", handle_requst, method="POST", body="req_time: %s no.: %s" % (time.time(), num))
```

I think you will get more along the lines of what you expect (first request transmitted instantly, instead of waiting for the run() method to break -- which takes about 2 seconds).

Second, you are doing exact compare on times (fx if now_time == begin_time:), in this example you round to int so it will work some times at least. But using techniques like this will make your programs blow up eventually. Time in computer clocks aren't as precise as you seem to think, there are many processes running and sleep(0.1) might be more than 0.1 second.

Third, you seem to expect your system to do instant communication to and from the network card, this will not happen.

Fourth, what you log as begin_time is not the variable begin_time, and you save the rep_time before you wait out the delay you impose in the server, not sure this is intended.

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep` blocks the IOLoop, which doesn't allow anything else to run (including the AsyncHTTPClient). For tornado to work smoothly, you must replace all blocking functions with non-blocking equivalents (for example, `yield gen.Task(IOLoop.current().add_timeout, datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))` instead of `time.sleep(1)`).

Comment: Hi, Ben, I modified the code, but still not the effect I want.I do not know how to do